# Is there a way I can somehow pull all tabs I have open on my screen using python? On windows

Tags: python, windows, tabs

I am making a small project of mine and I got stuck here, so basically I need a way to get my program a list of all the tabs I have open. So I need a way to tell my program all the tabs I have open (exmpl. firefox, chrome, spotify...) and then it needs to find all tabs starting with a specific word.

```py
import win32gui

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        print (hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))

win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, None )
```

I tried this yes it works but I need it to find all the windows starting with the same word but then have other words. So for example EVE is a game when you join in on a account that windows is called EVE - (then the name of the account) but when you have multiple accounts they r not always gonna be the same name so I need it to find all the tabs starting with EVE.

This is the output of this code.

```py
0x100ec 
0x1014e 
0x2033a Python - Get Started - Untitled (Workspace) - Visual Studio Code
0x40370 C:\Users\Leon\Desktop\Evetest2screenshot.py - Notepad++
0x102b0 Is there a way I can somehow pull all tabs I have open on my screen using python? On windows - Stack Overflow 
- Google Chrome
0x1041a Signal
0x22082a New Tab - Google Chrome
0x3038c Command Prompt
0x30426
0x1084c Setup
0x101e4
0x101d8
0x101c6
0x101a4
0x101a2
0x70060 Microsoft Text Input Application
0x203aa Spotify Premium
0x20178 Program Manager
```

Comment: Attach your output what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this. I have made the following which gives you a dictionary with a path if you desire to check it and a set/list of program names.

```py
import psutil

main_programs = {}
program_list = set()

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        if proc.cmdline() != []:
            main_programs[proc.name()] = proc.cmdline()[0]  # Get the name and path to a dictionary
            program_list.add(proc.name()) # Get the name to a set
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        print("No perms")


search = "p"
for item in program_list:
    if item.startswith(search):
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
powershell.exe
pythonw.exe
pycharm64.exe
```

**EDIT**

```py
list_programs = []
def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    win32gui = {}
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        list_programs.append(win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))
        print (hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))
search = "P"

for item in list_programs:
    if item.startswith(search):
        print(item)
```

Output

```
Python - Get Started - Untitled (Workspace) - Visual Studio Code
Program Manager
```

Comment: I just tried this and I don't get an output out of it. But I don't see why it wouldnt work. EDIT: It works thank you so much I just did something wrong.

Comment: Updated my code to alert you if there is an error @Void

Comment: I added the output just to alert you @FluxedScript

Comment: I just tried this updated version I don't get an output, just nothing happens.

Comment: I mean it doesn't have to include the whole code of mine I meant something in the lines of this. @FluxedScript

Comment: Not even sure why @Void but at least the code works. If I have solved this you should mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but it also gives me a list of all the processes. But is there a way to implement the search function into this?

```
    import win32gui

    def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
    print (hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))

    win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, None )
```